# How can I get the wikipedia image from Wikidata page

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata

Given a wikipedia image page such as

[https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2180_-*Pittsburgh*-_Mellon_Arena_-*Genesis*-_The_Carpet_Crawlers.JPG](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2180_-_Pittsburgh_-_Mellon_Arena_-_Genesis_-_The_Carpet_Crawlers.JPG)

I can get to the actual image url by using

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&redirects&format=xml&titles=*UrlFromLastSlash*

e.g

[https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&redirects&format=xml&titles=File:2180_-*Pittsburgh*-_Mellon_Arena_-*Genesis*-_The_Carpet_Crawlers.JPG](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&redirects&format=xml&titles=File:2180_-_Pittsburgh_-_Mellon_Arena_-_Genesis_-_The_Carpet_Crawlers.JPG)

But starting from the wikidata page such as

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q151012

thats contains an image how do I get to the commons File page (or indeed directly to the final image page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using prop=images will get you the commons file name which you can then add to your previous query:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=images&titles=Q151012